# Change the name of the dropdown menu according to selection in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dropdown

There is this dropdown menu in my Angular web-application:

```html
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">NAMEOFDROPDOWN
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/first">First</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/second">Second</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/third">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the name of the Dropdown, where currently reads NAMEOFDROPDOWN, to change to whatever is the name of the route that I select from the dropdown.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for [routerLinkActive]? https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links

Comment: I would like the name of the dropdown, where it says "Random title" in my sample code, to change to name of the route (First, Second, Third) which I select by openening the dropdown and clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a `click` event to the list elements like:

```
<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/first" (click)="changeRoute('First')">First</a></li>
<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/second" (click)="changeRoute('Second')">Second</a></li>
<li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/third" (click)="changeRoute('Third')">Third</a></li>
```

Then in your component's `.ts`-file you define a method `changeRoute(route)` which set's an attribute `selectedRoute`.

```
export class YourComponent  {
  selectedRoute = "default value";

  changeRoute(route: string) {
    this.selectedRoute = route;
  }
}
```

and finally you bind the value of your dropdown button to this attribute:

```
<button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"> 
   {{selectedRoute}}
<span class="caret"></span></button>
```