# When bootstrap dropdown item is selected, button text disappears

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu. When I choose an item from the dropdown menu, the text of the button is changed to the text value of the choosen item *(implemented by the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029507/7061548)*.

I have to reload the window whenever an item from the dropdown menu has been chosen because I update the sessionstorage. This works fine after page reload. But I have a problem before reload. As soon as I click on an item from the dropdown menu, the menu button becomes fully green and the button text disappears just before the page is reloaded.

I found out that if I remove the class "btn-outline-success" from the button the problem seems to be gone. I have tried to apply css styles on various elements but didn't succeed in solving the problem.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="m-dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-succes m-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
        {{selectedColor}}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="setColorGreen('Green')">Green</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="setColorBlue('Blue')">Blue</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
...
selectedColor: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedColor = "Green";
}

setColorGreen(color: string) {
    this.selectedColor = "Green";
    ...
    window.location.reload();
}

setColorBlue(color: string) {
    this.selectedColor = "Blue";
    ...
    window.location.reload();
}
...
```

Comment: I question whether you really need to reload the window when an option is selected. Couldn't you trigger an AJAX on select change?

Comment: doesn't related with your question but you send green as static and this function doesn't use this color and only change selectedColor to green. and you have 2 fn for this. (click)="setColorGreen('Green') and (click)="setColorBlue('Blue')" . You don't need 2 fn for this. you can simply send (click)="setColor('Blue')" and (click)="setColor('Green')"  and in your .ts  setColor(color: string) {
    this.selectedColor = color;
    ...
    window.location.reload();
}

Comment: @Chiperific I think I need to reload because I have to update the localstorage and then update the page. :)

Comment: @TalhaAkca Thank you for that, my code is much cleaner now :)

Comment: @Fth, if this is a strategy you know, it's ok, but almost all modern languages and frameworks have AJAX and JSON capabilities so you don't have to reload the page. A full page reload is usually much slower than sending a bit of data to the server with AJAX, handling the update to your database, and returning some JSON that you can then handle client-side.

Comment: It's because I need to save the data in sessionstorage so I think I need to reload the page to refresh the values, but actually I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as I click on an item from the dropdown menu, the menu button becomes fully green and the button text disappears just before the page is reloaded.

When you click the button Bootstrap fires some JS to trigger the dropdown.

It's using the `.dropdown-toggle` class and the `data-toggle="dropdown"`:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-succes m-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
```

I'm guessing that Bootstrap is marking the button as `disabled` so it can prevent double-clicks. And I'm guessing that the style change you're seeing is a result of some class changes that Bootstrap is making in JS as part of the button's click function.

If you have any defined CSS on the button, it could be conflicting with what Bootstrap is trying to do.

See the effect of clicking on a button on [Bootstrap's docs page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons). Does your change look at all familiar?

You can further test this in Chrome DevTools by looking at what fires when you click the button. Then put a breakpoint there and click the button.

Or you can use DevTools to force element state on the button to see what happens in different states (:active, :hover, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I found out that reloading the page was causing the problem. It looks like it can't complete the styling before the reload starts. I fixed this by adding a small delay on the function, because I need to reload the page.